# Make always rebuilding dependencies

Tags: makefile, targets

When I use a Makefile without variable targets, things work fine

```
preamble:
        mkdir -p data
        touch $@

data/a: preamble
        touch $@

data/b: data/a
        touch $@

data/c: data/a
        touch $@

data/d: data/b data/c
        touch $@

diamond: data/a data/b data/c data/d
        touch $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf ${data} diamond preamble
```

However, when I introduce a target variable tasks involved are always run.

```
data="data"
preamble:
        mkdir -p ${data}
        touch $@

${data}/a: preamble
        touch $@

${data}/b: data/a
        touch $@

${data}/c: data/a
        touch $@

${data}/d: data/b data/c
        touch $@

diamond: ${data}/a ${data}/b ${data}/c ${data}/d
        touch $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
        rm -rf ${data} diamond preamble
```

These are always executed

```
touch "data"/a
touch "data"/b
touch "data"/c
touch "data"/d
touch diamond
```

What is the correct way to include variables in target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not using quote marks. The Makefile does not need them, and they are confusing file names.

It is more common to say $(DATA) with parenthesis instead of ${DATA} curly braces.

Also, as a matter of practice, I recommend using variable names in all caps. Call it DATA instead of data.

Comment: @user3589054 - in `make` everything is a string. Quotes are treated as literal quotes. To assign `VAR=strings with spaces like this will work` works as expected.